# using multi bloc builder for one cubit (bloc)

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit

i have a cubit that has more than 2 lists, as follows

```
class HomeCubit extends Cubit<HomeState> {
  final HomeRepository homeRepository;

  HomeCubit(
    this.homeRepository,
  ) : super(HomeInitial());

  List<SubCatModal> mySubCat = [];
  List<SubCatModal> subCat() {
    emit(HomeLoaded());
    homeRepository.getSubCatRepository().then((respone) {
      emit(HomeSubCatSuccessCase(subCatList: respone));
      mySubCat = respone;
    });
    return mySubCat;
  }

  List<FirstSlideModal> myFirstSlider = [];
  List<FirstSlideModal> sliderListCubit() {
    emit(HomeLoaded());
    homeRepository.getFirstSliderRepository().then((respone) {
      try {
        emit(HomeFirstSliderSuccessCase(firstSliderList: respone));
      } catch (e) {
        emit(HomeErrorCase(message: respone));
      }
      myFirstSlider = respone;
    });
    return myFirstSlider;
  }
}
```

and in the app route, I use the following

```
case Routes.homeScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => BlocProvider(
            create: (BuildContext context) =>
                HomeCubit(HomeRepository(homeApi: HomeApi())),
            child: const Homepage(),
          ),
        );
```

and I call the cubit by using

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var subCubit = BlocProvider.of<HomeCubit>(context).subCat();
  }
```

so how can I build a multi bloc builder for each myFirstSlider and subCat in the UI through one cubit

Comment: you should provide code of HomeCubit, and try to describe what you are trying to achieve in more details.

Comment: i have edited my question, you can see it now @VladyslavUlianytskyi

Answer (score 1):

short answer - no way.
you don't need multi bloc builder. moreover, if you thinking this way then there is something you don't get clear enough.

anyway, you shouldn't hold lists in cubit. they should be in state, that should be [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) or [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed) e.g.:

```
class HomeState extends Equatable {
  const HomeState({
    this.isLoading = false,
    this.mySubCat = const [],
    this.myFirstSlider = const [],
  });

  final bool isLoading;
  final List<SubCatModal> mySubCat;
  final List<FirstSlideModal> myFirstSlider;

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [isLoading, mySubCat, myFirstSlider];

  HomeState copyWith({
    bool? isLoading,
    List<SubCatModal>? mySubCat,
    List<FirstSlideModal>? myFirstSlider,
  }) =>
      HomeState(
        isLoading: isLoading ?? this.isLoading,
        mySubCat: mySubCat ?? this.mySubCat,
        myFirstSlider: myFirstSlider ?? this.myFirstSlider,
      );
}
```

You can pass repos to your cubit:

```
class HomeCubit extends Cubit<HomeState> {
   const HomeCubit({
     required this.homeRepository,
     required this.profileRepository,
     required this.whateverYouNeedRepository
   });

   final HomeRepository homeRepository;
   final ProfileRepository profileRepository;
   final WhateverYouNeedRepository whateverYouNeedRepository;
...
   void subCat() {
     emit(state.copyWith(isLoading: true));
     homeRepository.getSubCatRepository().then((respone) {
      emit(
       state.copyWith(
              subCatList: respone, isLoading: false,
       ),
      );
     });
}
```

one more potential problem here that you create your cubit in router.
more clear:

```
...
case Routes.homeScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) =>  const Homepage(),
          ),
        );
```

where `Homepage` is:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => 
        HomeCubit(HomeRepository(homeApi: 
          HomeApi()))
            ..subCat()
            ..subCat() ,
      child: const HomeView(),
    );
  }
}
```

then you use BlocBulder for whole screen or just for one widget, that need this data:

```
class HomeView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        BlocBuilder<HomeCubit, HomeState>(
          builder: (context, homeState) {
            return Container(
            .. get data from state that you need
            );
          },
        ),
        //widget1,
        //widget2,
        //...
        BlocBuilder<HomeCubit, HomeState>(
          builder: (context, homeState) {
            return Container(
            .. get data from state that you need
            );
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: what if the mySubCat and myFirstSlider do the same work, should I have 2 cubit for each API? what if I have 4-6 apis in the homepage? i will create 4-6 cubits?

Comment: it depends entirely on your requirements. it is perfectly acceptable to have one qubit per screen. however, if, for example, the data myFirstSlider  for the second widget is reused for a widget on another screen, then it is logical to make a separate сubit for reuse for the second widget on another screen.

Comment: so, my question here is how to use one qubit that holds many API fetching functions in just one screen, because I use only one API in one cubit

Comment: nothing prevents you from injecting different repositories into one сubit, which in turn will pull different APIs, or directly transfer different APIs to the сubit.

Comment: it gives me only one functionion by screen by one cubit

Comment: something wrong there. all functions from cubit are accessible on every screen, where cubit is accessible.

Comment: that's what i really want to know, what is the problem is in my code, you can see my code in my question

Comment: if result of the method subCat() you need on screen start, right? when you need sliderListCubit() ?

Comment: i need both methods to start on the same time, I put them on homepage screen

Comment: updated answer with
HomeCubit(HomeRepository(homeApi: 
          HomeApi()))
            ..subCat()
            ..subCat() 

https://dart.dev/language/operators#cascade-notation

Comment: i got your code but the problem here is when I use in the bloc builder for sub cat:   if (state is HomeSubCatSuccessCase) {} else{text("loading sub cat"}  and I use bloc builder for first slider: if (state is HomeFirstSliderSuccessCase) {} else{text("loading first slide"}. when i emit HomeFirstSliderSuccessCase the widget of sub cat goes to else because i emit HomeFirstSliderSuccessCase not HomeSubCatSuccessCase

Comment: that is why I told: it depends entirely on your requirements. code here is not code that you could copy/past. it is pseudo code that gives you some direction to move forward. with your new requirements you need one state instead of a few. answer updated.

Comment: i got what you mean, thank you so much for your help